# node js, json, sql, tables

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js

hey everyone I am working with nodejs and express framework. I am trying to design a client side page which can be used to enter the form data into database i.e Mysql.So far I have succeeded to enter and retrieve the data from the database. Now I want to show this result in a tabular form where I can edit or delete the records dynamically. But I am unable to arrange the data into datatables. I am using json.stringify to pass the results to client side. The results are showing in this manner <"result:323 id=:321">

Answer (score 0):

You can send the html page with the desired table as response instead of     <"result:323 id=:321">. This is not advisable, though. Please refer to client side scripting tools like [angularjs](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) or [reactjs](https://facebook.github.io/react/)